# Use blob as src image

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, blob

I'm storing images as blob in my MySQL BDD.
I call my node API that return me my BDD lines with JQuery Ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mydinners.fr:5280/partner",
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(text){
        for(var i=0; i<text["message"].length; i++){
            var objurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(text["message"][i]["partner_image"]));

            // text["message"][i]["image"] is an array of point like : [192,257,54,269,85,458,...]

            var module = "";
            module += "<img class='activator' src='"+objurl+"'>";

            $(".container .row").append(module);
        }
    }
});
```

The objurl value is something like this : "blob:http%3A//dev.mydinners.fr/e73c5c6f-562e-4b66-9d4e-7a4c8567532e"

But the image is like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhma7.png

Do you know how to translate my blob image from mysql to img ?
thx.

Comment: You are making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content type of. What is `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` doing in there?

Comment: Thanks @Quentin to try to help me, found it on Google. Don't realy understand what I'm doing here, do you say me to remove this line ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the array to a binary data (using Uint8Array) before creating the blob

`var binary = new Uint8Array(json.message[0].partner_image)`

This is somewhat irrelevant, but it's a working example when you use Uint8Array, I just choose my own way of fetching/printing the data

```js
fetch("http://mydinners.fr:5280/partner")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
  let binary = new Uint8Array(json.message[0].partner_image)
  let blob = new Blob([binary])
  let img = new Image()
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  document.body.appendChild(img)
})
```

Comment: Amazing, THX @Endless !

Comment: Note, that `fetch` and es6 arrow functions `=>` and `let` is not working well in all browser, so you better stick to you code ;)